# How can I get a list of the flashing Windows taskbar items in Python?

Tags: python, windows, winapi

How can I get a list of the flashing Windows taskbar items?

For example, I'll have an IM client. When I get an IM, the item in the taskbar would go orange, as there's a notification in the window.

I would like to write a script that watches for these notifications and takes an action when it sees one.

My use case is rather special, but: I run a linux box with a Windows 7 virtual machine. I have a Cisco Jabber client in the VM, and the VM is very easy to work with, however I want to push the notifications to my linux desktop, so I know when to look at the VM.

So, how would I implement this function?

```
def get_highlighted_taskbar_button_count():
    # function that returns the number of taskbar flashing taskbar items
    pass
```

Comment: There is no such api function. You might install a global hook for FlashWindow and FlashWindowEx

Comment: Yes, I've done a bit of searching around, it is in fact not a simple API call, else I would have just called it in the implementation. But I don't have much experience with Windows programming, so don't have much clue where to start doing what you just said.

Comment: No, it's not easy. I don't see an alternative though. Even then, it might not even work. I think this task might not be worth the effort.

Comment: This isn't going to run reliably. Any taskbar button can flash for a number of reasons. Either access the IM's automation interface (if there is one), or filter the network traffic to the VM.